# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for activemq.xml

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to configure an ActiveMQ broker in a Spring Boot 2.1.7 application, specifically to enabled the statisticsBrokerPlugin.

My activemq.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core
        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <amq:broker brokerName="broker1" persistent="false">
        <amq:plugins>
            <amq:statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
        </amq:plugins>
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://embedded?broker.persistent=false,useShutdownHook=false"/>
        </amq:transportConnectors>
    </amq:broker>

    <amq:connectionFactory id="jmsFactory" brokerURL="vm://embedded"/>
</beans>
```

integrated using

```
@ImportResource("classpath:activemq.xml")
```

in a Kotlin / Gradle application with build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-activemq")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")    {
        exclude(module = "junit")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1")
}
```

Starting the application fails with

```
Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core]
Offending resource: class path resource [activemq.xml]
```

I'm finding a few posts regarding an issue with a Maven plugin, but nothing with Gradle.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Spring requires definition of META-INF/spring.handlers when adding non-Spring configuration in XML (as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html). The META-INF/spring.handlers definition for ActiveMQ is defined in

```
implementation("org.apache.activemq:activemq-spring")
```

and this dependency is NOT added by the Spring Boot "spring-boot-starter-activemq". So adding above line in build.gradle.kts resolved the issue.

Beware that there are further issues when building a shadow JAR (=fat JAR Gradle-style), as the various META-INF/spring.** files need be merged. https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-spring-woes-issues-in-creating-single-jar-b has more on this.